# how to get the string "submitted" into the citation call-out when using the apalike bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, apa-style

I need to cite a submitted-but-not-yet published journal article, and I follow this approach:

ref.bib

```
@preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " }
@article{author2015,
  author  = "Author Author", 
  title   = "Title Title",
  year    = "\noop{2015}submitted",
  journal = "Some Journal",
  ... }
```

In the text I type: `A study by \citet{author2015}`

which gives: `A study by Author (tted}`

So it seems that only 4 characters are possible. How can I get "submitted" to show up in the citation call-out?

file.tex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
A study by \citet{author2015}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good question!  Would you please add a minimal working example of your TeX file that shows the error?  Also, what is your build process?  In what order are you running TeX (pdflatex?) and bibtex?

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? It would appear that you're using a style that truncates the `year`field to the last four characters. The proper fix involves modifying/disabling the truncation setting. To do that, though, you need to tell us the exact bibliography style you're using.

Comment: and I build as following: pdflatex file.tex pdflatex file.tex pdflatex file.tex bibtex file bibtex file bibtex file pdflatex file.tex

Comment: I do not get any error messages during compilation, it is just in pdf file

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting and lightly touching up some of your write-up to clarify your objective to other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify the bibliography style file -- here: `apalike.bst` -- to get BibTeX/LaTeX to print "submitted" rather than "tted" in the citation call-outs. I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, and name the copy (say) `myapalike.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `myapalike.bst` in a text editor; the editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In `myapalike.bst`, find the function `calc.label`. (In my copy of this file, the function starts on line 896.)
- In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
    year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$
  ```

  In case you're curious: the instruction `purify$ #-1 #4 substring$` extracts the final four characters from the `year` string. Usually, this will be the ordinary four-numeral year string; in the case at hand, though, it's "tted".
- Change this string to

  ```
    year field.or.null
  ```

  i.e., delete the `purify$ #-1 #4 substring$` part.
- Save the file `myapalike.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- Start using the modified bibliography style by changing the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` macro. Be sure to re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more* to fully propagate all changes.

---

Consider the following MWE that's based on your code snippets:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myref.bib}
@preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " }
@article{author2015,
  author  = "Author Author", 
  title   = "Some Title",
  journal = "Some Journal",
  year    = "\noop{2015}submitted",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
A study by \citet{author2015}
\bibliographystyle{myapalike}
\bibliography{myref}
\end{document}
```

After running LaTeX and BibTeX, the file `\jobname.bbl` -- the file that contains the sorted and formatted bibliographic entries -- looks like this:

```
 \newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Author, \noop{2015}submitted]{author2015}
Author, A. (\noop{2015}submitted).
\newblock Some title.
\newblock {\em Some Journal}.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Observe that the term `\noop{2015}submitted` occurs *twice*. It occurs first in the optional argument of the `\bibitem` instruction. The optional argument is used by `natbib` to format the citation call-out. E.g., `\citet{author2015}` will generate `Author (\noop{2015}submitted)`, and `\citep{author2015}` will generate `(Author, \noop{2015}submitted)`. In both cases, LaTeX will then evaluate `\noop{2015}`, making the citation call-outs look like `Author (submitted)` and `(Author, submitted)`, respectively.

The term `\noop{2015}submitted` occurs again later on, this time surrounded by parentheses. Of course, `(\noop{2015}submitted)` is evaluated by LaTeX to `(submitted)`, and that's what you see in the typeset output.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you, Mico! Since the file was 'read-only' I had to say ':w !sudo tee %' in vim to be able to save changes, and indeed rerun texhash. Maybe this is the case only on my system, but perhaps other users may have a similar issue.

Comment: @Olga - Thanks for this observation. The read and write settings of various files and directories depend importantly on the TeX distribution you use. By the way, did you edit the original file (`apalike.bst`) or a copy?

Comment: I edited a copy of apalike.bst